# Latency Ethernet (LAN)

Tags: router, lan, gateway, latency

I just bought a CAT6 Ethernet cable from Amazon for $20, The length of cable is 20m and I am receiving 2ms - 150ms to my gateway, It's very rare that it peaks to 150ms but I've never saw my LAN go higher than 1ms.

Could the 20m in length be affecting it that much?

Comment: "Could the 20m in length be affecting it that much?" No - you should not see any measurable difference (assuming the cable is not damaged). If the cable is damaged you may experience packet loss which can affect the apparent latency as measured by a ping test.

Answer (score 1):

No, signals (electrons in copper in this case) can go 20m in about 68ns. So the effect of cable length within a LAN is like 5 or 6 orders of magnitude too small for you to measure with a ping RTT.

Gigabit Ethernet ping RTT on an idle network should be less than 1ms. The ranges you're getting suggest congestion or an underperforming router that takes too long to reply to ping requests.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: to test if the router is performing or not, disconnect all devices except your device - over Cat6 - router and ping the router. If you got 1ms, that means your cable is most likely fine. Start connecting all other devices (let normal traffic use the router), and then ping the router again - you SHOULD get 1ms as well (as you are 1 hop away from it). If you are getting weird result, then your router is underperforming as Spiff said. If you are sending ping to an outside server (beyond the router/LAN) - then all bets are off.